# Batch Task Execution of a Feature Collection in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, batch, tasks

I have generated a Feature Collection for a geometry with 6 polygons. Formatted the table and then exported the first three feature collections having over 1000 properties. However the last batch file times out giving a computation error.

Link to the code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/6c29596851cc826a98b73fdfc0dde165

Asset Link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=projects/ypm-rs-ml/assets/farms_6

```
.
.
// Part of the code used to generate the last feature collection to be exported as table later
// Apply smoothing

var oeel = require('users/OEEL/lib:loadAll');
var order = 3;

var sgFilteredCol = oeel.ImageCollection.SavatskyGolayFilter(
  regularCol, 
  maxDiffFilter,
  distanceFunction,
  order)
// This fails as computation times out
print(sgFilteredCol.size(), sgFilteredCol.first())

// Table 4:
var viBandsSmoothed = sgFilteredCol.select(bandsListForSmoothing)
//print('viBandsSmoothed', viBandsSmoothed)

var vegIndicesSmoothed = viBandsSmoothed.map(function(image) {
  var withStats = image.reduceRegions({
  collection: geometry,
  reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
  scale: 10
  }).map(function(feature) {
    return feature.set('imageId', ee.Date(image.get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd'))
  })
  return withStats
}).flatten()

var format = function(table, rowId, colId) {
  var rows = table.distinct(rowId); 
  var joined = ee.Join.saveAll('matches').apply({
    primary: rows, 
    secondary: table, 
    condition: ee.Filter.equals({
      leftField: rowId, 
      rightField: rowId
    })
  });
  
  return joined.map(function(row) {
      var values = ee.List(row.get('matches'))
        .map(function(feature) {
          feature = ee.Feature(feature);
          // ['ndvi','gndvi','evi2','savi','ndre','ndwi','rvi','dvi','mcari']
          var ndvi = ee.List([feature.get('d_0_ndvi'), -9999]).reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull());
          var gndvi = ee.List([feature.get('d_0_gndvi'), -9999]).reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull());
          var evi2 = ee.List([feature.get('d_0_evi2'), -9999]).reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull());
          var savi = ee.List([feature.get('d_0_savi'), -9999]).reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull());
          var ndre = ee.List([feature.get('d_0_ndre'), -9999]).reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull());
          var ndwi = ee.List([feature.get('d_0_ndwi'), -9999]).reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull());
          var rvi = ee.List([feature.get('d_0_rvi'), -9999]).reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull());
          var dvi = ee.List([feature.get('d_0_dvi'), -9999]).reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull());
          var mcari = ee.List([feature.get('d_0_mcari'), -9999]).reduce(ee.Reducer.firstNonNull());
          
          return [[ee.String(feature.get(colId)).cat('_ndvi'), ee.Number(ndvi).format('%.3f')],
                  [ee.String(feature.get(colId)).cat('_gndvi'), ee.Number(gndvi).format('%.3f')],
                  [ee.String(feature.get(colId)).cat('_evi2'), ee.Number(evi2).format('%.3f')],
                  [ee.String(feature.get(colId)).cat('_savi'), ee.Number(savi).format('%.3f')],
                  [ee.String(feature.get(colId)).cat('_ndre'), ee.Number(ndre).format('%.3f')],
                  [ee.String(feature.get(colId)).cat('_ndwi'), ee.Number(ndwi).format('%.3f')],
                  [ee.String(feature.get(colId)).cat('_rvi'), ee.Number(rvi).format('%.3f')],
                  [ee.String(feature.get(colId)).cat('_dvi'), ee.Number(dvi).format('%.3f')],
                  [ee.String(feature.get(colId)).cat('_mcari'), ee.Number(mcari).format('%.3f')],
                 ];
        });
        
      return row.select([rowId]).set(ee.Dictionary(values.flatten()));
    });
};

var timeSeriesSmoothed = format(vegIndicesSmoothed, 'Farm_Id', 'imageId');

Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: timeSeriesSmoothed,
  description: 'smoothed',
  folder: 'earthengine',
  fileNamePrefix: 'smoothed',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'})
```

Tried a couple of Batch export options and also to export the table as an Asset if that helps. It was not helpful. Is there any way to perform the operation tile-wise and then export in batches or export the final feature collection itself in batches?

Answer (score 0):

"Error: User memory limit exceeded. (Error code: 3)"

I think it's one of the most requested errors about GEE. You are most certainly trying to compute too much data on a too big surface.

As a mitigation solution try to reduce the scale of your reducer (currently 10m)

Also if you want to get a better answer, try to create a minimal reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), it will show that you did try to find a solution on your own and exclude the code that does work (I guess that out of these 400 lines, some is working).